# Fetch Flask Data from python

Tags: python, mysql, reactjs

I have some code from python that displays a table using Flask and render template. I'd like to place this into my React App.js file how can I do this?

[My CRUD from python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiQ3S.png)

I'd like to place that into App.js.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: May be you need `axios`

Answer (score 0):

You can create API in flask and call from react js with axios package.
Install axios with

```
npm install axios
```

**Simple Example:**
Suppose you API is localhost:8080/hello

and it returns "Hello world"

In app.js imports,

```
import axios from "axios";
```

and in return

```
return (
<div>
axios.get("localhost:8080/hello")
</div>
)
```

References:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios